# Make "default" page the parent page of a custom taxonomy archive page

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I was wondering if it's possible to use a default page I've created in my WordPress dashboard as a parent to my custom post types'.

My default page is: 'www.example.com/about'

My custom post type is: 'team'

My custom post types' custom taxonomy is: 'teams'

My Goal is: 'www.example.com/about/teams/sales/'

Is there a way to achieve this URL structure or do I have to include my about page in my custom taxonomy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you register your taxonomy you can change the **rewrite** parameter of the $args to alter the slug.

```
$args = array(
    'labels'            => $labels,
    'public'            => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => false,
    'hierarchical'      => false,
    'show_tagcloud'     => true,
    'show_ui'           => true,
    'query_var'         => true,
    'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'about/teams' ), // this line here
    'query_var'         => true,
    'capabilities'      => array(),
);

register_taxonomy( 'teams', array( 'team' ), $args );
```

After you make this change you may need to re-save your permalinks to see the effects.